# How send the value from one screen to another screen in .py file?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have a checkbox on my ModelsettingScreen and I want to send the received checkbox value, like pick_cloth to my ResultScreen. How can I do this?

In the code below, I marked the relevant lines.

```
class ModelsettingsScreen(Screen):
    def SwitchScreen(self,destination:str):
        self.manager.current = destination
    def model_inference(self, stop_event, start_time):
        # Event stops the thread if cancel in dialog is pressed
        if stop_event.is_set():   
            return
        ids = self.ids      
        pick_cloth = self.ids.cloth_pick.active
        print("pick_cloth = ",pick_cloth )
  
class ResultScreen(Screen):
    def SwitchScreen(self,destination:str):
        self.manager.current = destination

    def create_list_results(self,results):
        print(self.manager.get_screen('ModelsettingsScreen').model_inference.pick_cloth)
        #print("pick_cloth=",self.parent.ids['ModelsettingsScreen'].model_inference.pick_cloth)

class App(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

    # provides the filemanager object

    super().__init__(**kwargs)

    self.filemanager = MDFileManager(select_path=self.select_path,exit_manager=self.exit_manager,preview=True)



    def build(self):

    # loads the gui structure from a kivy specific dataformat

        gui = Builder.load_file('app2.kv')

        return gui
```

For the app2.kv file:

```
<ModelsettingsScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: "Model setting"

            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_dark  
  

          
    BoxLayout:           
        CheckBox:
            group:'check'
            active:
            id: cloth_pick
            color:0,0,0,1
```

I can get the checkbox value from the ModelSetting Screen with True or False. Then I try the 2 methods like the last 2 print lines.

```
print(self.manager.get_screen('ModelsettingsScreen').model_inference.pick_cloth)
#print("pick_cloth=",self.parent.ids['ModelsettingsScreen'].model_inference.pick_cloth)
```

But both of they report the following AttributeError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "/home/user002/Digital_decor_2.0/digital_decor_app2.py", line 956, in <module>

     App().run()

   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 955, in run

     runTouchApp()

   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 574, in runTouchApp

     EventLoop.mainloop()

   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 339, in mainloop

     self.idle()

   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 379, in idle

     Clock.tick()

   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 733, in tick

     self.post_idle(ts, self.idle())

   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 776, in post_idle

     self._process_events()

   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 620, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events

   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 653, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events

   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 649, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events

   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 218, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick

   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/animation.py", line 371, in _update

     self.stop(widget)

   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/animation.py", line 236, in stop

     self.dispatch('on_complete', widget)

   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 727, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch

   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1307, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch

   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1231, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch

   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/uix/screenmanager.py", line 419, in _on_complete

     self.screen_in.dispatch('on_enter')

   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch

   File "/home/user002/Digital_decor_2.0/digital_decor_app2.py", line 449, in on_enter

     self.create_list_results(output_data)

   File "/home/user002/Digital_decor_2.0/digital_decor_app2.py", line 459, in create_list_results

     print(self.manager.get_screen('ModelsettingsScreen').model_inference.pick_cloth)

 AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'pick_cloth'
```

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is. Your are trying to reference `model_inference.pick_cloth`, but `model_inference` is a method. You can call methods, but they do not have attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I fixed my error. Just update some code as the following:

```
class ModelsettingsScreen(Screen):
    pick_cloth = False
    def SwitchScreen(self,destination:str):
        self.manager.current = destination
    def model_inference(self, stop_event, start_time):
        # Event stops the thread if cancel in dialog is pressed
        if stop_event.is_set():   
            return
        ids = self.ids      
        self.pick_cloth = self.ids.cloth_pick.active
        print("pick_cloth = ",self.pick_cloth )
  
class ResultScreen(Screen):
    def SwitchScreen(self,destination:str):
        self.manager.current = destination

    def create_list_results(self,results):
        print(self.manager.get_screen('ModelsettingsScreen').model_inference.pick_cloth)
```